# CaIendar Rebuses

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

Here are some caIendar-styIe rebuses.
The tags are the hint.

1. > $\dfrac{\mathrm{MAY}}{\sf\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\sf Sun& \sf Mon&\sf Tue&\sf Wed&\sf Thu&\sf Fri&\sf Sat\\ \sf {\color{red}{sos}}&2&3&4&5&6&7\\ 8&9&10&11&12&13&14 \\ 15&16&17&18&19&20&21 \\ 22&23&24&25&26&27&28 \\ 29&30&31& & & &\end{array}}$  [cryptic-clues](/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues)
2. > $\dfrac{\mathrm{SEPTEMBER}}{\sf\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\sf Sun& \sf Mon&\sf Tue&\sf Wed&\sf Thu&\sf Fri&\sf Sat\\ Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z\\ Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z \\ Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z \\ Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z&Z \\ Z&30& & & & &\end{array}}$  [music](/questions/tagged/music)
3. > $\dfrac{\mathrm{DECEMBER}}{\sf\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\sf Sun& \sf Mon&\sf Tue&\sf Wed&\sf Thu&\sf Fri&\sf Sat\\ 1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\ 8&9&10&11&12&13&14 \\ 15&16&17&18&19&20&21 \\ 22&23&24&{\color{#00ff00}{25}}&26&27&28 \\ 29&30&31& & & &\end{array}}$  [seasonal](/questions/tagged/seasonal)
4. > $\dfrac{\mathrm{JULY}}{\sf\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\sf Sun& \sf Mon&\sf Tue&\sf Wed&\sf Thu&\sf Fri&\sf Sat\\ 1^{\circ}\mathsf{C}&2&3&4&5&6&7\\ 8&9&10&11&12&13&14 \\ 15&16&17&18&19&20&21 \\ 22&23&24&25&26&27&28 \\ 29&30&31& & & &\end{array}}$
5. > $\dfrac{\mathrm{MARCH}}{\sf\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\sf Sun& \sf Mon&\sf Tue&\sf Wed&\sf Thu&\sf Fri&\sf Sat\\ 1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\ 8&9&10&11&12&13& {\color{#ffffff}{14}} \\ 15&16&17&18&19&20&21 \\ 22&23&24&25&26&27&28 \\ 29&30&31& & & &\end{array}}$ [cryptic-clues](/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues)

Suggest some more in comments.
l'm Iearning to use $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ right now, and l need practice.
The tags below are for all the clues above.

Comment: l was inspired by a question l previously asked. That question contains a calendar rebus l found on Bing.

Comment: What's up with the title using `I` instead of `l`? Is that necessary for the puzzle?

Comment: This puzzle inspired a copycat puzzle, @Scratch---Cat , thank you for leading the way!

Answer (score 16):

I believe the answers may be:

> 1. **MAYDAY** (the 'SOS' expression and also traditionally the name given to the 1st of May) [*Double definition*];
>
>  2. **Wake Me Up When September Ends** (a [song](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_Me_Up_When_September_Ends) by Greenday) [*All days except the last are replaced by 'Z's to indicate sleep*];
>
>  3. **Green Christmas** (the [term](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Christmas) given to a Christmas day without snow on the ground) [*Christmas Day (25 December) is coloured green*];
>
>  4. **A cold day in July** (an expression equivalent to "When Hell freezes over...") [*The temperature '1°C' appears on the first day of July*];
>
>  5. **Pie hole** (a [slang term](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pie+hole) for the mouth) [*A hole is left on 14 March, otherwise known as Pi Day*].