# A sneak peek at July, 2034

Tags: rebus

[image]

This calendar page contains all the rebuses you’ll need
to help prepare for July, 2034.

1. Saying that reputedly evolved from a Welsh nursery rhyme
2. Saying that is also in a pop song’s lyrics
   (along with, thanks to
    [eyl327’s solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97854),
    a song’s title and album name
    previously unknown to this rebus’s maker)
3. Figure of speech that is also a pop song’s title
4. Figure of speech that has become a meme
5. U.S.A. holiday
6. North American term related to astronomy
   (not well known but can be looked up from clues)
7. Another term related to astronomy

***What are these rebuses and
   why is July, 2034, the soonest month that can convey
   rebuses 5, 6 and 7 in Alaska on one calendar page?***

**Late addition**
(not required for a  **✓** correct solution)
thanks to
[Damila’s solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97889)**:**

8. Saying related to wages

<sub>Hint for #4, the picture that accompanies the meme:</sub>

> [image]
>  <sup>([HBO](https://www.hbo.com/movies/cast-away))</sup>

<sub>Credit
[Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat)
for leading the way with
[Calendar
 Rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97648/caiendar-rebuses).</sub>

Comment: Of course, one rebus is quickly recognizable :D

Comment: Re "wrong date" for the USA day where we broke free of the Crown. When it falls on a Saturday or Sunday, the federal holiday for purposes of federal employees, banks, etc, i steh closest weekday.

Comment: **Note to solvers unfamiliar with USA holidays:**
If you search with Google be sure to include the year 2034
because [_a misleading date_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJRfo.png)
is obtained when queried with just "USA holidays in July"

Comment: will there be hints? :0

Comment: Thank you for the excuse to add a hint, @oAlt . Rebus #4 now has one while #6 already has a pretty strong hint about using an internet search.

Comment: It's not clear which ones are solved, and 2&3 and 6&7 makes it difficult to differentiate the clues.

Comment: True, @user110503, i consider #6 to be the only unsolved rebus. I hope your solution for #4 winds up in [eyl327's collection of solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97854), which has both #2 and #3 even if one is a different pop song than intended.

Comment: @humn but 2&3 only have one answer (not including the unintended additional answer)?

Comment: Right again, @user110503 , so i revised my comment above and now your solution has helped eyl327 complete the entire puzzle. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.

> [An apple a day keeps the doctor away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_apple_a_day_keeps_the_doctor_away)
>  (PhD is kept away by having an apple on every day of the month)

2. & 3.

> <s>[Blue Monday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Monday_(New_Order_song))</s>
>
>  [Every Day Is a New (nu) Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Every_Day_Is_a_New_Day) (song title, album, and lyrics)
>
>  Additionally, [8 days a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Days_a_Week) by the Beatles. [[@JMP](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97855/65935)]

4.

> <s>[Get the Third Degree](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+third+degree+from) (?) (PhD is called "third degree" in some languages)</s>
>
>  [Counting down the days](https://media.makeameme.org/created/just-counting-down.jpg) [[@user110503](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99543/65935)]

5.

> <s>[V-Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_Day) (?) or [Black Friday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Friday_(shopping)) (although other days are also black)</s>
>
>  [Fourth of July](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(United_States)) ($7.75/31$ of the days are shaded black = $1/4$) [[@shoover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97947/65935)]

6.

> <s>Black Hole</s>
>
>  [Buck moon](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/moon/buck.html) (Moon in July. Buck also means a dollar).

7.

> [Blue Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_moon)

July 2034, the soonest month that can convey rebuses 5, 6 and 7 in Alaska on one calendar page because

> It is the soonest there will be two full moons (the second being a Blue Moon) in July. July is necessary since Buck Moons and 4th of July only occur in July. 4th of July is a United States holiday so it would happen in Alaska.

Comment: A hint for the year: rot13(Whyl rvtugu bs gjragl guvegl-sbhe vf gur ynfg dhnegre bs gur zbba cunfr.  Abgr gung gur oybpx vf guerr-dhnegref svyyrq.)

Comment: I think the PhD placed outside the calendar is to signify keeping the Doctor away in 'An apple a day keep the Doctor away'

Comment: @humn interesting. Can I ask, what was the intended song for 2/3? And why are there 2 dollars at the end if 8 was an extra one not there originally? I must be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7):

3.

> [8 days a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Days_a_Week) by the Beatles.

Answer (score 5):

5. U.S.A. holiday is

> Fourth of July

because

> July has 31 days and exactly $\frac{31}{4}$ squares, or one-fourth, are shaded black

3. has been answered, but here's another that fits:

> If I Could Turn Back Time (by Cher)

because

> The month goes from 31 to 1

Comment: Thank you for explaining #5, @shoover, it was the most fun to concoct

Answer (score 4):

One of these is

> **Once in a blue moon** Explanation: 2 full moons and the second is blue.

6, or 7?

8.

> **Another day, another dollar**

Answer (score 2):

Is 4.

> Counting down the days ?